# Cakephp 1.3 pagination with search criteria not working as expected

Tags: cakephp, search, pagination, cakephp-1.3

I have set simple search in my project.  I need to display the results based on search criteria. When I Click on the second page of the paginate button it shows the whole results means search criteria is missing. How to paginate with search criteria.

Thanks in Advance.
Prasanth

Answer (score 0):

You need to merge your url params so that the search is carried over to the next page.

`$this->Paginator->options(array('url' => $this->passedArgs));`